# lsass and svchost should they access internet or not? On WXP-SP3

Tags: windows-xp, internet, firewall, svchost, lsass

My Zone Alarm 8 firewall on WXP-SP3 is advising me:

- svchost.exe (Generic Host Process for
  Windows 32 services)
- lsass.exe (LSA
  Shell (Export version)

both try sometimes to access internet.

Should I allow bothj or one of them to access internet or not???
I Googled about this, but I can't find an answer. YES or NO!

Thanks!

Comment: eh - **SP4** ???

Comment: No such thing as XP sp4, well not yet anyway.

Comment: LOL if Windows is really telling you you have Service Pack 4, I would say reformat and reinstall.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it's WXP-SP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes svchost has to access the internet for certain features and software to work.

If you are sure it is Lsass, and not Isass, it is OK to let it access the local network.

Isass is part of the sasser worm.

Comment: Ho do I know the difference?

Comment: The sasser worm exploits a vulnerability in Lsass, sorry, its not the file itself.

Lsass should be located in the System32 folder, if it is found elsewhere it could be malware masquerading as a system file.

If you run virus scans regularly, you are probably ok.